# Randomly present text beside pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivot table that summarizes user feedback on a coffee store. The original data has the user's actual feedback (User Comment), and I assigned a category to each feedback and the category groups the feedback based on their similarities (Category). Next, I assigned a higher-level category that groups the Category (Topic).

In sum, there are multiple groupings, with User Comment (raw data) <- Category (2nd level of grouping) <- Topic (1st level of grouping).

The pivot table summarizes the Topic and shows the Category underneath the Topic in a column.

Here, you can see the data and pivot table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bVFtfqCgdCvTKdjm_g2dXcNiOw3Zuijs/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102977197595787113580&rtpof=true&sd=true

I want to click each Category in the table and have **three random** user feedback associated with that category appear on the right side of the table.

Right now, 'Show Details' does not quite do what I want. Can I do what I want using a Slicer/Macro or any other means?

I'd appreciate your insights.

Comment: You can look at using the worksheet `selection_change` event to figure out which category the user clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for example.

Code goes in the worksheet code module for the sheet with the pivot table.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, v, listCell As Range
    Dim pt As PivotTable, col As Collection, c As Range

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'single-cell selections only...
    
    Set pt = Me.PivotTables(1) ' or use PT name
    
    'selected a "category" cell?
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, _
            pt.PivotFields("category").DataRange) Is Nothing Then
        v = Target.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then 'any value in this cell?
            Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("datasource")
            Set col = New Collection
            'checvk source data and collect comments
            For Each c In wsData.Range("C2:C" & _
                wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
                If c.Value = v Then col.Add c.Offset(0, -1).Value
            Next c
            Set listCell = Me.Range("B21")
            listCell.Resize(3).ClearContents 'clear any previous
            If col.Count > 0 Then 'if got any matches...
                ListRandom col, 3, listCell
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

'Given a collection of text items, list `numItems` random entries,
'  starting at cell `rngStart`
Sub ListRandom(col As Collection, numItems As Long, rngStart As Range)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    For i = 1 To numItems
        n = Application.RandBetween(1, col.Count) 'pick random index
        rngStart.Offset(i - 1).Value = col(n)     'show on sheet
        col.Remove n                              'remove selected item
        If col.Count = 0 Then Exit For            'no items left?
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this worked for you, to help out anyone coming along later with a similar problem.